# Setting the template property on Yii2 GridView / ActionColumn?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

First ... old school, rusty Pascal/Clipper/VB developer trying to learn PHP and Yii2 at the same time.

Looking at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$template-detail I should be able to easily remove the update and delete buttons in the ActionColumn ... I just don't know how / where to set the property.

Our GridView code is:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'email1:email',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'], 
    ],
]); ?>
```

My gut tells me it's something to do with instantiating the ActionColumn class before we throw that in as a column ... but I've combed the forums and documentation and just can't find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the template properly. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$template-detail

your column should be

```
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => "{view}",
        ],
```

Comment: Yeah, I just hit IRC ... was silly that I didn't realize you basically can set parameters by adding the 'template' as another key/value pair here.  Thanks though!